# Lambda function blanks DynamoDB values

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

During 1min cycle I get 2 events(mqtt messages) which goes into a Lambda function (.js).

Event no.1:

```
{
  "ID": 789,
  "Value1": 1,
  "Value2: 2,
}
```

Event no.2:

```
{
  "ID": 789,
  "Value3: 3
}
```

**Issue:** At the moment my Code first puts the Event no.1 into a row in the DB. When Event no.2 arrives it overwrites and BLANKS the Value1 and Value2, so after a minute I end up with only Value3 in the DB.

**Question:** How can I edit the  code so it just fills out the values which is empty in the DynamoDB row?
I have experimented with ConditionExpression but without success..

```
console.log('Loading function');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var table = "TABLE";

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
   var params = {
    TableName:table,
    Item:{
        "ID": event.ID,
        "Value1": event.Value1,
        "Value2": event.Value2,
        "Value3": event.Value3,
        "TimeStamp": String(Math.round(Date.now() / 60000) * 60000)
        },    
    };

    console.log("Adding...");
    dynamo.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to add. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            context.fail();
        } else {
            console.log("Added:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Update**:

Edited the code with "dynamo.update" instead of "dynamo.put". Now the code cannot create a new row. Json log gives missing-key error.

```
console.log('Loading function');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var table = "TABLE";

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
   var params = {
    TableName:table,
    Item:{
        "ID": event.ID,
        "Value1": event.Value1,
        "Value2": event.Value2,
        "Value3": event.Value3,
        "TimeStamp": String(Math.round(Date.now() / 60000) * 60000)
        },    
    };

    console.log("Adding...");
    dynamo.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to add. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            context.fail();
        } else {
            console.log("Added:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            context.succeed();
        }
    });
}
```

**TABLE in DynamoDB configure:**

```
Table name  TABLE
Primary partition key   TimeStamp (String)
Primary sort key    -
```

Comment: The API for `update` is different than the one for `put`. As the error states, you need to pass a `key` parameter to the call, among other things. See the `update` documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html):

> **putItem**(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
>
> Creates a new item, or
>   replaces an old item with a new item.

---

> **updateItem**(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
>
> Edits an existing
>   item's attributes, or adds a new item to the table if it does not
>   already exist.

So you need to change your code to use `updateItem` instead of `putItem`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But when I tried that the code couldnt creat a new row (each minute a new row should be created as the Timestamp is the Key in the DynamoDB table).. Perhaps it is possible to tweak it a little?

Comment: Tweak what exactly? The documentation clearly states that `updateItem` will create a new row if one does not exist. If that isn't working for you then maybe you should ask a new question with the details of that.

Comment: This is the error from the log:
Error JSON: {
  "message": "Missing required key 'Key' in params",
  "code": "MissingRequiredParameter",

Comment: Edit your question to include the code with `updateItem`, and also include the schema definition of your table.

Comment: Edited the post, see above! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can Update what you get `Event Object`.
So you have to **dynamic query** for that.

**Example for a dynamic query for update by id**

```
let event = {
    ID : '123',
    Value1 : 'qwe',
    Value2 : 'qweqwe'
  };
  let id = event.ID;
  delete event.ID;
  let expression = 'SET ';
  let expressionAttribute = {};
  
  for (var key in event){
        console.log(key)
        expression += key + ' = :' + key + ', ';
        expressionAttribute[':'+key] = _.get(event,key);
  }
  
  expression = expression.substr(0, expression.length-2);

  let queryParams = {
    TableName: 'table',
    Key: {
      'ID': id
    },
    UpdateExpression: expression,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expressionAttribute,
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
  };

  documentClient.update(queryParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('failure:update data from Dynamo error', err);
    } else {
      console.log('success:update data from Dynamo data', data);
    }
  });
```

For this example when you log `expression` and `expressionAttribute`

> expression is : SET Value1 = :Value1, Value2 = :Value2
>
> expressionAttribute is: { ':Value1': 'qwe', ':Value2': 'qweqwe' }